# ColdFusion <CFSELECT> Syntax: Required="yes": Does it actually work?

Tags: coldfusion, cfform

I am trying desperately to understand if the **required="yes"** option actually works with a ColdFusion CFSELECT?

It works with other inputs, but I just cannot get it owrking on a CFSELECT. Not much info on the Adobe Support site other than size <> 1 etc, but I am looking for a simple dropdown, not a list box.

Tearing my hair out.
Thanks,
Jack

Comment: It is hard to help with no information or code example. Did you see the note in the docs: _This attribute has no effect if you omit the size attribute or set it to 1_  You really should move away from using any of the CF... UI stuff.  They are limited and end up being more work than needed. [CFUI the right way](https://github.com/cfjedimaster/ColdFusion-UI-the-Right-Way)

Comment: I would recommend trying required="true".  Coldfusion's yes/no strings instead of true booleans is still crazy today, and I've been doing CF over 20 years.  To be honest, veterans of CF tend to move away, long term, from things like cfform, cfinput, etc. in favor of vanilla HTML.  For the very reason you're struggling.  It's unpredictable, it's under the hood and black-boxed.  And you can simply do straight HTML.

Comment: A `required` attribute for a `select` is meaningless because the form always submits a value, even if that value is an empty string.  Consider writing a js function that checks to see if the user select a real value and calling it when the form is submitted,

Comment: All, thanks for all the feedback - and sorry no response sooner. I got a bought of COVID which was maybe a good thing as it gave me some time to rest up on this.
I have parked the Required=Yes and went back to using Jquery to validate the form. All working as required and many thanks. The only thing I cannot get working is validating if a checkbox is checked or unchecked, but I will continue on that. Sorry again and thanks a ton -